# Rumor Socket Disconnected: Connectivity loss was detected as it was too long since the socket received the last PONG message

Tags: javascript, sockets, gruntjs, opentok, tokbox

While using **Opentok** plugin for video chat (client version - 2.2.5.1 , server Node sdk - 2.2.3) , i get this error after publishing to the session :

> *Rumor.Socket: Rumor Socket Disconnected: Connectivity loss was detected as it was too long since the socket received the last PONG message*

Along with that i also get this error :

```
OT.SessionDisconnectEvent{
  type: "sessionDisconnected",
  cancelable: true, 
  preventDefault: function, 
  isDefaultPrevented: function, 
  reason: "networkDisconnected"
}
```

It does say `"reason" : "network disconnected"` , but i have double checked and nothing seems to wrong with the network connection .

This is the code i have been using :

```
    session = TB.initSession(TOK_API_KEY,session_id);
       session.on("sessionDisconnected", function(event) {  
                    console.log("SESSION DISCONNECTED: "+new Date());
                    console.log(event);
                 });

                session.on('sessionConnected', function(e){
                    console.log("SESSION CONNECTED");
                    var prop = {width: 400, height:300, name:"My Video"};
                    publisher = TB.initPublisher("broadcast_display", prop, function(error) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log('error initializing publisher', error);
                        } else {
                            console.log('publisher initialized successfully');
                        }
                    });
                });

                session.connect(token, function(error) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Published: "+new Date());
                        session.publish(publisher);
                    }
                });
```

The session terminates after this and the publishing also stops . The time it takes to disconnect after publishing starts and the disconnection is consistent (53 secs . Not sure if this is relevant) .

I have also been using GruntJS and EmberJS along with Opentok .

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in OpenTok when used with EmberJS. This bug has been found and fixed and should be released in the JS update late this week or next week.